# Mandatory Manifest-Version attribute missing

Tags: java, android, gradle, compiler-errors

So I just update the compileSdkVersion to 26 and can't seem to find what's causing this issue when compiling:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mandatory Manifest-Version attribute missing

Only thing I've tried is adding the version codes to the manifest instead of the gradle file but doesn't seem to impact anything.

Here's part of my gradle build file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.com"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode xxx
        versionName "x.x.x"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst  'META-INF/*'

    }
    dexOptions {
         javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

And the whole stacktrace:

> [10:58:50] john@bob:project$ gradle assembleDebug --stacktrace
>
> > Configure project :app  Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead. Configuration
> >     'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use
> >     'androidTestImplementation' instead. Configuration 'testCompile' in
> >     project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead. The
> >     CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is
> >     scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the
> >     CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.
> >             at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(CompileOptions.java:273)
> >             at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions_Decorated.setBootClasspath(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.JavaCompileConfigAction.execute(JavaCompileConfigAction.java:77)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.JavaCompileConfigAction.execute(JavaCompileConfigAction.java:31)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:148)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskContainerAdaptor.create(TaskContainerAdaptor.java:58)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.AndroidTaskRegistry.create(AndroidTaskRegistry.java:45)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.AndroidTaskRegistry.create(AndroidTaskRegistry.java:87)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createJavacTask(TaskManager.java:1510)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.addCompileTask(ApplicationTaskManager.java:263)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.lambda$createTasksForVariantScope$12(ApplicationTaskManager.java:224)
> >             at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.createTasksForVariantScope(ApplicationTaskManager.java:220)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:641)
> >             at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:636)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$3(BasePlugin.java:555)
> >             at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$4(BasePlugin.java:551)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
> >             at
> >     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
> >             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
> >             at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
> >             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> >     registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
> >     registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices 
>   Parsing json file: /.../project/app/google-services.json
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
>   > Failed to generate v1 signature
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
>         at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:314)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:204)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
>         at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
>         at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
>         at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>         at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to generate v1
>     signature
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$10(OutputScope.java:241)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:236)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:197)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:181)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:471)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>         ... 103 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
>         at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:297)
>         at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.access$200(SigningExtension.java:55)
>         at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1.lambda$beforeUpdate$2(SigningExtension.java:175)
>         at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2099)
>         at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:871)
>         at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1161)
>         at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:189)
>         at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:216)
>         at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:332)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:700)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:522)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(OutputScope.java:186)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(OutputScope.java:203)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$null$8(OutputScope.java:225)
>         at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:235)
>         ... 118 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mandatory Manifest-Version attribute missing
>         at com.android.apksig.internal.jar.ManifestWriter.writeMainSection(ManifestWriter.java:47)
>         at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.generateManifestFile(V1SchemeSigner.java:363)
>         at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.sign(V1SchemeSigner.java:253)
>         at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.outputJarEntries(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:372)
>         at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:295)
>         ... 133 more
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s 26 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 22 up-to-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst  'META-INF/*'

    }
```

This is why your run fails. Remove this lines and everything be fine.

Comment: This is the second time I ran into this issue, this didn't fix it the first time but did the second, what does pickFirst do?

Answer (score 4):

The stacktrace pointed me to [this line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/apksig/internal/jar/ManifestWriter.java#48) which looks for `Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION`.

Per [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Attributes.Name.html) `Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION` is `Manifest-Version`.

Then I saw the jar causing my issues had a MANIFEST.MF but the file was empty.  All the other MAINFEST.MF files had one line:  `Manifest-Version: 1.0`.

I added `Manifest-Version: 1.0` to the empty MAINFEST.MF which solved my problem.

**Note:** You can rename the .jar file to a .zip file and can open it using any compression tool such as winrar or winzip to see/edit the content.

Comment: How did you find the jar which caused the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Piggy-backing off Steven's answer, which helped me solve it:

> Then I saw the jar causing my issues had a MANIFEST.MF but the file was empty. All the other MAINFEST.MF files had one line:  Manifest-Version: 1.0.

Some jars are missing the MANIFEST-INF folder and MANIFEST.MF file inside it. You can quickly view the contents of imported .jar files using Android Studio's Project Explorer and the /libs/ folders of your module(s)

Find the jar missing these and go to Finder/Explorer/Terminal to unzip the jar, add the missing manifest, and re-zip the jar.

**To View MANIFEST.MF** (Android Studio Example)

**Pitfall:** When you re-zip the file be sure to choose .zip compression and only zip the inner files, not the folder itself (ex some.jar creates ../somejar/, only zip the contents of ../somejar/.., otherwise you may find yourself with `java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`.

[image: To view contents of jars]

[image: Select Inner Folders to re-zip, not the external folder]

[image: WinRar shown here, creating a .zip archive]

Answer (score 0):

In case your project has Foreground services, do not put two in one package. That doesn't really relate to the stackTrace but may help some people who will come here googling for this issue.

Also switching to another branch, making invalidate-cache-restart (button in "File" menu of your Android studio and building on another branch and after that returning to your own may help. At least it did for me.